# Double click on node in Force Directed Graph, theJit

Tags: javascript, dom-events, visualization, thejit

I'm trying to add in a double click on a node in the force directed graph from thejit package found here : [force directed graph](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/ForceDirected/example2.html)

Double clicking on the node name is easy enough, but I can't seem to figure out how to add a double click to the node itself.  I've tried a lot of different things, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this buy adding in two single clicks on the node.  Worked well.